# Bind data from ionic to iframe(own website)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, iframe

I want bind the data in ionic that i inserted for login and then iframe to my own website page ,the database is already connected in within both.

In other word says is  when i use ionic login and it success authentication with the php and then it will redirect to it own account.

Help me check which part should i improve.

login.ts

```
 login(){
 this.authService.postData(this.userData,'login').then((result) => {
  this.responseData = result;
  if(this.responseData.userData){
  console.log(this.responseData);
  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
  this. presentLoadingDefault();
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
  else{ {swal({
    title: "Invalid Username or Password",
    text: "Please Try Again",
    icon: "warning", })
     } }
}, (err) => { console.log("something wrong~")
  // Error log
});

 }
```

auth-service.ts

```
postData(credentials, type) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let headers = new Headers();

  this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res.json());
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
}
```

home.html

```
  <html>
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
 <img ion-right class="navbarLogo" />
   <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>

 <ion-content class='padding has-subheader' scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true">
   <iframe class='webPage' name="eventsPage" src="http://www.wiptrainee.com/taxsentral/member/dashboard.php">
  </iframe>
 </ion-content>
 </html>
```

Comment: Dont store authdata unencrypted on the phone.

Comment: sorry, what that mean???